# Insert dynamic listbox options in Tinymce popup editor

Tags: javascript, listbox, tinymce

I am trying to create dynamic listbox values but getting this error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of [

Here's my code( pasting only the code for listbox ):

```
 body: [
                {
                    type: 'listbox',
                    name: 'type',
                    label: 'Panel Type',
                    value: type,
                    'values': get_author_list(),
                    tooltip: 'Select the type of panel you want'
                },
        ]
.....
```

And I am calling this function to get dynamic list...

```
  function get_author_list() {
    var d = "[{text: 'Default', value: 'default'}]";

    return d;
}
```

I am guessing that the values in listbox only takes static var and not dynamic. But I need to insert dynamic values in this list. Please can anyone help me find a workaround. Is there any possibility to insert via ajax?

Thanks, in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for .NET site. Even though is not great code I hope it can help someone.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('DocumentSelector', function (editor, url) {
// Add a button that opens a window
editor.addButton('DocumentSelector', {
    text: 'Document',
    icon: false,
    title: "Document Selector",
    onclick: function () {
        var _documentList;

        //load all documents
        var _data = JSON.stringify({/* Some data */});

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/TinyMCE/GetDocuments",
            data: _data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
                _documentList = eval('(' + data + ')');

                // Open window
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Document Selector',
                    body: [
                    {
                        type: 'listbox',
                        name: 'DocURL',
                        label: 'Documents',
                        values: _documentList
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'textbox'
                        , name: 'TextToDisplay'
                        , value: _text
                        , label: 'Text To Display'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'textbox'
                        , name: 'TitleToDisplay'
                        , value: _title
                        , label: 'Title'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'listbox',
                        name: 'TheTarget',
                        label: 'Target',
                        values: [{ text: 'None', value: "_self" }, { text: 'New Window', value: "_blank" }],
                        value: _target
                    }
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function (e) {
                        // Insert content when the window form is submitted

                    }

                });

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Error! " + xhr.status + "\n" + error);
            }
        });

    }

});
});
```

And here it is some of the Behind code

```
public class TinyMCEController : ApiController
{

public class DocumentsInfo
{
    // Some data
}

public class DocumentList
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetDocuments")]
public object GetDocuments(DocumentsInfo docInfo)
{
    //Test data
    List<DocumentList> _DocumentList = new List<DocumentList>();
    _DocumentList.Add(new DocumentList  {
        text = "Document1.pdf",
        value = "value1"
    });

    _DocumentList.Add(new DocumentList
    {
        text = "Document2.pdf",
        value = "value2"
    });

    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(_DocumentList);
    return json;

}
}
```